# Disable fingerprint login after reboot of Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, login-screen, biometrics

For security measures, I'd like to force password-only logon after reboot or some timeout (1 hour+) on Windows 10. Biometrics could be used later only after successful password use, to unlock the laptop. It's possible to set up such logic on Android, but I have not found the same thing on Windows 10.

Comment: Unfortunately, Windows Hello authentication isn't something you can disable, then enable, without user intervention.  You could, in theory, disconnect the Biometric device, then reconnect it. This would disable the option to use that particular Windows Hello method to authenticate.  However, what you describe in your question, specifically is not possible though.